# PHP's _GET doesn't support if()

Tags: php, web, get

I'm using the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['TDEnderEmail']) || htmlspecialchars($_GET['TDEnderEmail'])){
  $VEENFSL = strval($_GET['TDEnderEmail']);
  if(strpos($VEENFSL, "@enderadel.cf") > 0 && strlen($VEENFSL) > 5 && strlen($VEENFSL) < 22){
    return true;
  }
}
```

and although that `$VEENFSL`'s `if (strpos($VEENFSL, "@enderadel.cf") > 0 && strlen($VEENFSL) > 5 && strlen($VEENFSL) < 22`) statements values are turn for the example -`user@enderadel.cf`- `if()` never return a true

Answer (score 0):

Be warned that `strpos` doesn't work like you probably think it does: as the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) states, `strpos`

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the
>   beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note
>   that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.
>
> Warning This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

This means that your example string probably matches at position 0, therefore

```
strpos($VEENFSL, "@enderadel.cf") > 0
```

is `false`.

Therefore, you should replace that with

```
strpos($VEENFSL, "@enderadel.cf") !== false
```

Comment: `strpos()` works as I think it does, and your solution doesn't work (I've tried it before)